# pytest -rP logs twice for each test

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django, cookiecutter-django

I'm building a test suite for a small Django app and am using pytest. When I run the tests with `docker-composec -f local.yml run --rm django pytest -rP`, it logs each test twice. I added a timestamp to the function being tested (`2022-02-20 20:57:32.196975+00:00`) and they are identical so I don't think its running the tests twice, but outputting them twice.

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ TestAggregateTiltReadings.test_initial_run _______________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stderr call ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO 2022-02-20 20:57:32,196 services 1 140188905805632 2022-02-20 20:57:32.196975+00:00
INFO 2022-02-20 20:57:32,197 services 1 140188905805632 Aggregating 4 new tilt readings
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:33 2022-02-20 20:57:32.196975+00:00
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:34 Aggregating 4 new tilt readings
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ TestAggregateTiltReadings.test_initial_run _______________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stderr call ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO 2022-02-20 20:57:32,196 services 1 140188905805632 2022-02-20 20:57:32.196975+00:00
INFO 2022-02-20 20:57:32,197 services 1 140188905805632 Aggregating 4 new tilt readings
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:33 2022-02-20 20:57:32.196975+00:00
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:34 Aggregating 4 new tilt readings
```

I used cookiecutter-django to start the app and am using the default settings. I'm not sure what configs to share which might be helpful to troubleshoot this. I can add some if there are any ideas.

EDIT

pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --ds=config.settings.test --reuse-db
python_files = tests.py test_*.py
```

Using `docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django pytest . -rP --capture=no`

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ TestAggregateTiltReadings.test_initial_run _______________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:33 2022-02-21 02:38:09.635703+00:00
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:34 Aggregating 4 new tilt readings
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ TestAggregateTiltReadings.test_initial_run _______________________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:33 2022-02-21 02:38:09.635703+00:00
INFO     brew_dash.tilts.services:services.py:34 Aggregating 4 new tilt readings
```

EDIT 2 the offending test:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestAggregateTiltReadings:
    def test_initial_run(self, tilt_hydrometer_factory, tilt_reading_factory, caplog):
        next_cutoff_dts = timezone.now()
        tilt = tilt_hydrometer_factory.create()

        # Ensure there's a few TILT readings as would be expected for an initial run
        tilt_reading_factory.create(tilt_hydrometer_uuid=tilt)
        tilt_reading_factory.create(tilt_hydrometer_uuid=tilt)
        tilt_reading_factory.create(tilt_hydrometer_uuid=tilt)
        tilt_reading_factory.create(tilt_hydrometer_uuid=tilt)

        # last_cutoff_date equaling None makes this an initial run test
        gravity, temp = aggregate_tilt_readings(tilt, None, next_cutoff_dts)

        assert "Aggregating 4 new tilt readings" in caplog.text
        assert is_gravity_valid(int(float(gravity) * 1000))
        assert is_temp_valid(temp)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a `StreamHandler` configured that prints logs to stderr (you can test that by passing `--capture=no` that will stop capturing stderr) and logs capturing turned on somewhere in the pytest configuration (you can test that by passing `-p no:logging` that will disable logs capturing). Decide what you want to have and disable the other.

Comment: Adding `--capture=no` removed the `stderr` lines, but it didn't remove the duplicate of the test themselves: TestAggregateTiltReadings.test_initial_run is still in there twice. Adding `-p no:logging` broke some of my tests which test the log messages. I've added the updated output above